# What sets the left file pane margin for Sublime Text 3 UI themes?

Tags: user-interface, themes, sublimetext3

I'm using the Soda Dark UI theme for Sublime Text 3 and I'd like to increae the left margin within the pane. It looks too tight, to me.

What class(s) is used to define that margin?

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you are looking for is ***sidebar_container*** and the property is ***content_margin***.

I see in your screenshot that you already know what file you need to look in, but maybe is usefulf for other users to know that you can create a file called *Soda Dark 3.sublime-theme* inside Packages/User for your overrides with the following content:

```
[
    // Soda Dark 3 theme overrides
    // Sidebar container
    {
        "class": "sidebar_container",
        "content_margin": [10, 0, 1, 0]
    }
]
```

The value of *content_margin* has the following syntax so in this case you need to change the first value for the left margin value you want:

```
[left, top, right, bottom]
```